# Laravel 5 getting input values that are arrays

Tags: php, laravel, input, laravel-5, laravel-form

I have a text field like

```
{!! Form::textarea('representive[address_1]' ,null ,['class' =>'textboxlong form-control','style'=>'height:60px;']) !!}
```

In my form. And when I try to get its value in my controller but it comes null. What I try is

```
$adress = Request::get('representive.0.address_1');
```

I also tried some other ways but could not end up with a proper solution. How can I get the value of this field? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Request::get('representative');` and then take the values from that array?

Comment: Just do `Request::get('representative.address_1');`.  The ".0" part is what shouldn't be there.  Also you misspelled the variable as "$adress" by the way.

Comment: @orrd `Request::get('representative.address_1');` does not work. I tried it already

Comment: Oh, sorry I actually what I should have said was `Input::get('representative.address_1');`.  The `Request::get()` method doesn't understand dot notation because it's a Symfony method.  Otherwise, Joel Hinz's answer would also work if you need to use Request::get() for some reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Request::get()` method is implemented by [`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_get) which the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class extends. This method does not parse the string parameter passed using the dot notation as Laravel does. You should instead be using the [`Request::input`](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_input) which does:

```
$adress = Request::input('representive.address_1');
```

As an alternative you can also use the `Input` facade and do `Input::get()`.

Comment: I just tested `Request::input('representive.address_1');` and it works just fine. Try doing a `dd(Input::all());` in your controller and see if you are actually getting the parameter value from the client.

Comment: The value of that `{!! Form::textarea('representive[address_1]' ,null ,['class' =>'textboxlong form-control','style'=>'height:60px;']) !!}` field does not appear in `dd(Input::all());` array when i return it, not sure why.

Comment: Then it most likely has something to do with the form itself. Please post more code from your form. How are you submitting the form: synchronously or with an AJAX request?

Comment: Ajax would be more complex as i am a L5 newbie. Rest of the form seems fine, which part of the form might be causing this problem do you think ?

Comment: I can't really say without seeing the entire form code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80528/discussion-between-tartar-and-bogdan).